# Docker private registry insufficient_scope when trying to delete image

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-registry

I'm trying to delete an image tag from my private docker registry mydockerregistry.com within a bash script. Authentication is done through registry web mydockerregistry.com:8080, so I get the token first using

```
TOKEN=`curl -s \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user myuser:mypassword \
    "http://mydockerregistry.com:8080/api/auth?service=mydockerregistry.com&scope=repository:my-repo/:*" \
    | jq -r .token`
```

WIth this token I can browse the registry, get the tag I want to delete, etc. Using the tag number I get the digest using

```
DIGEST=`curl -vk \
    -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept:application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
    https://mydockerregistry.com/v2/my-repo/manifests/latest 2>&1 \
    |grep "< Docker-Content-Digest:" |awk '{print $3}'`
```

But then, when I run

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept:application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
  -X DELETE \
  https://mydockerregistry.com/v2/my-repo/manifests/$DIGEST
```

I get the error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="mydockerregistry.com:8080/api/auth",service="mydockerregistry.com",scope="repository:my-repo:*",error="insufficient_scope"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 21:29:00 GMT
< Content-Length: 160
< 
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"my-repo","Action":"*"}]}]}
* Connection #0 to host mydockerregistry.com left intact
```

I tried changing scope to pull; pull,push, but I always get the 401 still doing exactly what Www-Authenticate header says.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the problem.

The user I was trying to run the script with has a role 'admin' wich only had push and pull permissions, no *.

I created a new role called 'delete-repo' with permissions ' pull, push, * ' I assigned it to my user, and the magic happened.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that authentication is not the real issue (you can probably push and pull on that registry), did you enable deletes which are disabled by default?

https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#delete

Also note that once you delete manifests, the filesystem layers are still part of the registry, so your disk space consumption will not go down unless you run garbage collection.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

Comment: Thanks for replying! deletes are enabled in registry config .yml
delete:
  enabled: true
In fact, I can delete tags from registry web (one by one)

Comment: If you are that far then don't bother writing your own code. Here is a project that can clean out old versions: https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/deckschrubber

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing spaces after the colons on your headers (not sure if curl would automatically fix that), and there's no Accept header needed for the DELETE api:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -X DELETE \
  https://mydockerregistry.com/v2/my-repo/manifests/$DIGEST
```

Beyond that, double check the value of the token and digest in the command you're running, and then check the logs on the registry server.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added spaces but the result is the same. Also, if I echo token and digest values and manually run a GET query, it works. The same data, but with -X DELETE returns 401.